# Spring Boot Save entity

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

1. There is data in the form of json.

   ```
     {
         "type": "1C",
         "counterparty": {
             "name": "ИП Петя",
             "inn": "123456789",
             "kpp": ""
         },
         "nomenclatures": [
             {
                 "cod": [{"type":"1C", "val":"РТ-1234"}, {"type":"Front", "val":"567"}],
                 "name": "Картоха",
                 "article": "123"
             },
             {
                 "cod": [{"type":"1C", "val":"РТ-1234"}, {"type":"Front", "val":"567"}],
                 "name": "Сникерс",
                 "article": "459"
             }
         ]
     }
   ```
2. There is a database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrLku.png)

3.Now I want to save this entity to database.

4. I saved three entities. There is one entity left that I cannot save. Help save the fourth entity **Cod** to the database.

   ```
            @PostMapping(value = "/item")
            public void postMain (@RequestBody NodeObject node) {


                Counterparty counterparty = new Counterparty();
                counterparty.setName(node.getCounterparty().getName());
                counterparty.setInn(node.getCounterparty().getInn());
                counterparty.setKpp(node.getCounterparty().getKpp());
                counterpartyRepository.save(counterparty);


                NodeObject nodeObject = new NodeObject();
                nodeObject.setType(node.getType());
                nodeObject.setId(counterparty.getId());
                nodeObject.setCounterparty(counterparty);
                nodeObject.setNomenclatures(node.getNomenclatures());
                nodeObjectRepository.save(nodeObject);


                Set<Nomenclature> nomenclatures = node.getNomenclatures();
                nomenclatures.forEach(nomenclature -> nomenclature.setNodeObject(nodeObject));
                nomenclatureRepository.saveAll(nomenclatures);




                // ????????????????????????
                List<Cod> cod = new ArrayList<>();





            }
   ```

json comes to the controller. @RequestBody NodeObject node

Comment: I believe this is where you are getting it wrong `nomenclatures.forEach(nomenclature -> nomenclature.setNodeObject(nodeObject));`. Under nomenclatures, you should be able to get `nomenclature.getCod()` something like this , since nomenclature is a set consisting of distinct COD records!

Comment: @Harsh I agree with you that nomenclature.getCod() - I agree with you that nomenclature.getCod(). Just how to implement it. All the code is correct, but how to make the code?

Comment: Try something like this or similar `List<Cod> cod = nomenclatures.stream().filter( n -> n.getCod()).collect(Collectors.toList());` Let me know if it works!

Comment: @Harsh - This does not work. I have attached an image for you to see. - Bad return type in lambda expression: Set<Cod> cannot be converted to boolean - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAEpE.png